# Factory for extended Model in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, factory, extends, laravel-8

I'm facing an issue on laravel 8, I created :

- A class called `CRUDModel` that extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`
- A Model called `Stuff` that extends `CRUDModel`
- A factory called  `StuffFactory`

When I call `Stuff::factory()->count(60)->create();` I get this error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `stuffs` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-10-12 15:28:06, 2020-10-12 15:28:06))
```

I guess it's because of `Stuff` doesn't extend directly `Model` but I'm not sure.
Here's my class :

```php
<?php
namespace App\Crudite\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Crudite\Model\CRUDIntel;

class CRUDModel extends Model
{
    use CRUDIntel;

    ...
    
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Crudite\Model\CRUDModel;

class Stuff extends CRUDModel
{
    use HasFactory;
    ...
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Stuff;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class StuffFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Stuff::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            "title" => $this->faker->name,
            "content" => $this->faker->paragraph,
            "thumbnail" => "https://placekitten.com/1200/300"
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who may have the same problem, what @Kermito does for making a factory out of an extended model is actually correct. Simply make a factory out of the extended model, as you would a regular model and it should work. In this case, however, it is the `faker` functions for  `title` and `content` that have an error, which could be why they are not being added into the insert statement as shown in the error. Faker has updated their syntax and the lines of code should be:

```
//note the parantheses ()
 "title" => $this->faker->name(),
 "content" => $this->faker->paragraph(),
```